# When Nameservers are mapped, my domain redirects to the IP provided

Tags: dns, cloud, digital-ocean, nameservers

I have setup a wordpress website on Digital Ocean. I have domain registered on GoDaddy. I have created domain from Digital Ocean and mapped the name-servers to GoDaddy. But when I enter the url, it just redirects to the IP and IP is shown on address bar instead of domain name.
Is there anything else should I add?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that You are using DNS servers provided by DigitalOcean and mapped your droplet's IP to your domain, You need to add the following Name Servers in Your GoDaddy Configuration:

```
  ns1.digitalocean.com 
  ns2.digitalocean.com
  ns3.digitalocean.com
```

If it is still Redirecting to Your IP address then make sure in Your Apache/Nginx Vhost Block, there is no redirect defined in them.

Also, you are running Wordpress then it is possible that you had set up your site's URL as IP address, it might be the reason for redirect, if it is then make sure to change it from `wp-config.php` 
You can find more info here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Hope this Helps!